# Plotting euler approximation and analytical approximation using matplotlib in python giving unexpected output

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, lambda

I am trying to plot the euler approximation and analytical solution of a the differential equation dy/dx = x + y/5 with y(0) = -3

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def euler_method(step_size):
   first_x = 0
   last_x = 5
   h = step_size
   n = int((last_x-first_x) / h)
   x=0
   y=-3

   dy = lambda x,y: x + (y/5)
   f = lambda x,y: math.exp(x+(y/5))

   x_values = []
   euler_values= []
   analytical_values = []

   for i in range(1, n+1):
    x_values.append(x)
    euler_values.append(y)
    analytical_values.append(f(x,y))
    y = y + dy(x, y) * h
    x = x + h
    

   x_values.append(x); euler_values.append(y); analytical_values.append(f(x,y))

   plt.plot(x_values, euler_values, 'ro', x_values, analytical_values)
   plt.legend(['Euler values','Analytical values'])
   plt.show()

euler_method(1)
```

My output is this:

[image]

which is obviously incorrect but I am not sure why this is happening or what changes I would have to make to fix this.

Comment: worth cropping that image: we don't need the code a second time, but this time packed into an image.

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram Alpha gives [this analytical solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%27%3Dx%2B%28y%2F5%29%2C+y%280%29%3D-3) for your problem.  Yours does not look correct to me.    Doesn't agree with Stephen Wolfram.

I corrected your code.  Now it works fine:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75751065/plotting-euler-approximation-and-analytical-approximation-using-matplotlib-in-py
# Analytical solution: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=22+e%5E%28x%2F5%29+-+5+%285+%2B+x%29&assumption=%22ClashPrefs%22+-%3E+%7B%22Math%22%7D

def euler_method(step_size):
    first_x = 0
    last_x = 5
    h = step_size
    n = int((last_x - first_x) / h)
    x = 0
    y = -3

    dy = lambda x, y: x + (y / 5)
    f = lambda x, y: 22.0 * math.exp(x/5.0) - 5.0 * (5.0 + x)

    x_values = []
    euler_values = []
    analytical_values = []

    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        x_values.append(x)
        euler_values.append(y)
        analytical_values.append(f(x, y))
        y = y + dy(x, y) * h
        x = x + h

    x_values.append(x)
    euler_values.append(y)
    analytical_values.append(f(x, y))

    plt.plot(x_values, euler_values, 'ro', x_values, analytical_values)
    plt.legend(['Euler values', 'Analytical values'])
    plt.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    euler_method(0.01)
```

Here's the plot it generates:

[image]